# Comparing multiple data files

Tags: scripts

I have several files containing text data. I need each individual file to have only unique lines against all the other text files. For example, textfile1 has a line entry called "foobar", but so does textfile15. What is the best way to perform a comparison for uniqueness of the individual rows against multiple files?

Comment: And what do you want to be done with lines that are found in several files? Only display them? Remove them from the files?

Comment: If both `file1` and `file15` have `foobar`, which one should be kept? Is keeping the order of the lines important? Please [edit] your question, show us example input and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To find if all text files are unique:

```
cat *.txt | wc -l ; cat *.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

If the lines match they are unique.

To find what duplicates are present:

```
cat *.txt | sort | uniq -d
```

Here is a more complete scenario: 
I have songs downloaded. When I download new songs I want to ensure I am not repeating. 
So I would do

```
find . -name *.txt | sort -u > catalog.music
```

Now suppose I find a playlist which I would later download. And this play list is in downloadNew.txt . 
I would do

```
grep -F -f downloadNew.txt catalog.music
```

If search is unsuccessfull  downloadNew.txt is unique, else duplicates are present .